# Выполнение скрипта по крону. Крон не успевает отработать за указанное время.

Tags: php, linux

Всем привет. Товарищи, такая проблема/вопрос:

У меня есть крон, который **каждый час** запускает некий php-скрипт.

**Q:** Скажите, пожалуйста, если скрипт не успел выполнится за час, крон запуститься другим потоком или нет?

Дело в том, что у меня по каким-то причинам не запустился (

Спасибо.

Comment: Ага, другим потоком. Т.е. у вас уже будет работать 2 одинаковых скрипта.

Comment: Но, у меня он почему-то не запустился =(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> если скрипт не успел выполнится за час, крон запуститься другим потоком или нет?

демон *cron* работает постоянно.

да, процесс будет запущен новый.

> у меня по каким-то причинам не запустился

вполне возможно, что скрипт был запущен, но в нём, например, есть проверка на наличие работающего первого экземпляра.

уточните, запустился ли он, в логах, куда в вашей системе *cron* отчитывается. поискать файл можно среди таких, например, кандидатов:

```
$ grep -i cron /var/log/{daemon.log,syslog,messages}
```